# Strict mode statement causes functions to be undefined

Tags: javascript

I've wrapped all my functions around an immediately-invoked function expression as shown:

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  function toggleComment(parentCommentID) {
    $("form#" + parentCommentID).toggle();
  }

  function scrollBottom() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }

})();
```

However, upon calling one of these functions through a link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggleComment(159); return false;">Reply</a>
```

The Chrome console outputs `Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleComment is not defined`. Am I mistaken in thinking that an immediately-invoked function expression, as its name suggests, should be invoked immediately and therefore `toggleComment` should be called? Should I call the function differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `toggleComment` is not visible. It's enclosed in the ready function you're using; if you want to be able to call it like that (which is not recommended, in most cases), you have to hoist it outside of that function and make it globally accessible.

And this has nothing to do with `strict`. If you remove the `strict` line, this problem will still be the same.

Comment: Note: this has nothing to do with strict mode :-P

Comment: Aah, thanks for the explanation; I was a bit fuzzy on *how* strict mode was able to do its work until this.

Answer (score 2):

The functions are no longer declared in the global scope. Try

```
window.toggleComment = function(parentCommentID) {
  $("form#" + parentCommentID).toggle();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the functions inside a closure. They're outside of the scope of the HTML tag.

You could set an id to your `<a>` tag as well as publish your function to the global scope, so you can do this:

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  var toggleComment = function(parentCommentID) {
    $("form#" + parentCommentID).toggle();
  }

  function scrollBottom() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }

  document.getElementById("yourATagId").onclick(function() {
    toggleComment(159);
  });

  window.toggleComment = toggleComment;
})();
```

Maybe you could benefit from this simple singleton pattern:

```
(function() {
    var controller = {};

    controller = new function() {
        this.sampleProperty = "my property";
    }

    controller.yourFunction = function() {
        var localVariable;
        console.log("I can access " + this.property);
    };

    window.controller = controller;
})();
```

This way, `controller` will be known to your global scope.